# How to substitute value for a variable in a json in python?

Tags: python, json

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import uuid

random_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
print random_uuid
url = "http://192.168.54.214:8080/credential-store/domain/_/createCredentials"

payload = '''json={
        "": "0",
        "credentials": {
            "scope": "GLOBAL",
            "id": "random_uuid",
            "username": "testuser3",
            "password": "bar",
            "description": "biz",
            "$class": "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl"
        }
    }'''
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

In the above script, I created a UUID and assigned it to the variable `random_uuid`. I want the UUID that was created to be substituted inside json for the value `random_uuid` for the key `id`. But, the above script is not substituting the value of `random_uuid` and just using the variable `random_uuid` itself.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll can use string formatting for that.

In your JSON string, replace random_uuid with %s, than do:

```
payload = payload % random_uuid
```

Another option is to use `json.dumps` to create the json:

```
payload_dict = {
    'id': random_uuid,
    ...
}

payload = json.dumps(payload_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.format` instead:

```
payload = '''json={
        "": "0",
        "credentials": {
            "scope": "GLOBAL",
            "id": "{0}",
            "username": "testuser3",
            "password": "bar",
            "description": "biz",
            "$class": "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl"
        }
    }'''.format(random_uuid)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use direct JSON entry into a `dict`:

`payload = {
        "": "0",
        "credentials": {
            "scope": "GLOBAL",
            "id": random_uuid,
            "username": "testuser3",
            "password": "bar",
            "description": "biz",
            "$class": "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl"
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

This code may help.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import uuid

random_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
print random_uuid
url = "http://192.168.54.214:8080/credential-store/domain/_/createCredentials"

payload = '''json={
        "": "0",
        "credentials": {
            "scope": "GLOBAL",
            "id": "%s",
            "username": "testuser3",
            "password": "bar",
            "description": "biz",
            "$class": "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl"
        }
    }''' % random_uuid
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }

print payload

print(response.text)
```